# Merging Data in FMPro with modification of ID values

Tags: merge, foreign-keys, filemaker

We are attempting to merge multiple datasets created in in filmmaker pro.

These datasets have multiple tables, and each entry within each table has a local ID that is used to relate entries between tables. The local ID values for all the entries were serially generated values, but some of the ID values are repeated between the different datasets, though the indicated records are non equivalent.

How can the ID values be updated in the data that is being imported to remove these overlaps without destroying the relationships that depend on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the original database, you can try to migrate the ID's over to UUID or something unique before exporting. This has to be done manually, either cut/paste by hand or by a script.
Such a script will have do the following:

- Loop through the parent records
- For each record go to the related records
- Generate an UUID with the get(UUID) function and put it in a variable
- Replace the parent ID in the related record with this variable
- Return to the parent record and replace the record ID with the variable.
- Move to the next record.
- Repeat until all records have been updated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.